# Issue with Refactoring the existing code using Streams (Java8)

Tags: java-8, iteration, java-stream, refactoring

I'm new to Streams and using Java 8 version. I'm trying to refactor my existing code by using Streams.
Here is the code snippet:

```
       List<AddressAccessibility> addressAccessibility = entity.getAccessibility();
       List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (AddressAccessibility element : addressAccessibility) {

           String verificationHash;
           if (element.getVerification() != null) {
               verificationHash = verificationHashCodeGenerator(element.getVerification());
           } else {
               verificationHash = "No Verification";
           }
           String id = getFirstIdAndCache(element.getId(), IdReferenceTypes.ADDRESSACCESSIBILITY.getValue(),
                   IdReferenceTypes.ID.getValue());
           StringBuilder entryBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(id).append(DELIM)
                   .append(getPrimaryId(healthCareProvider.getId())).append(DELIM)
                   .append(getPrimaryId(element.getSuppliedId())).append(DELIM);
           if (element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory() != null) {
               entryBuilder.append(element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory().getCode()).append(DELIM)
                       .append(element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory().getShortName()).append(DELIM)
                       .append(element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory().getLongName()).append(DELIM);
           } else {
               entryBuilder.append(DELIM).append(DELIM).append(DELIM);
           }
           entryBuilder.append(element.getLocationAccessibilityText()).append(DELIM).append(verificationHash);

           String entry = replaceNullMethod(entryBuilder.toString());
           entries.add(entry);
       }
```

To refactor above code using streams, I tried like this :

```
Function<AddressAccessibility,String> address = (AddressAccessibility element) -> {

            String verificationHash;
            if (element.getVerification() != null) {
                verificationHash = verificationHashCodeGenerator(element.getVerification());
            } else {
                verificationHash = "No Verification";
            }
            String id = getFirstIdAndCache(element.getId(), IdReferenceTypes.ADDRESSACCESSIBILITY.getValue(),
                    IdReferenceTypes.ID.getValue());
            StringBuilder entryBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(id).append(DELIM)
                    .append(getPrimaryId(healthCareProvider.getId())).append(DELIM)
                    .append(getPrimaryId(element.getSuppliedId())).append(DELIM);
            if (element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory() != null) {
                entryBuilder.append(element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory().getCode()).append(DELIM)
                        .append(element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory().getShortName()).append(DELIM)
                        .append(element.getLocationAccessibilityCategory().getLongName()).append(DELIM);
            } else {
                entryBuilder.append(DELIM).append(DELIM).append(DELIM);
            }
            entryBuilder.append(element.getLocationAccessibilityText()).append(DELIM).append(verificationHash);

            String entry = replaceNullMethod(entryBuilder.toString());
            entries.add(entry);
        } 
}

 entity.getAccessibility().stream().map(address).collect(toList());
```

Is this the right approach to refactor the above code?. Please suggest the best way to refactor the above code.

Comment: Do you have the feeling that this new version is better, in any regard?

Comment: Agreed. I do not see a need to refactor a perfectly working code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the lambda expression is still quite complex. If I pretend that it is hidden as extracted to a method, then what will remain in refractored version is just conversion one list to another one by stream. Quite ok, but maybe not that needed. I would refractor that block lambda to several functions to have overall more understandable code (hopefully).

I can highly suggest following video:

Get a Taste of Lambdas and Get Addicted to Streams by Venkat Subramaniam
https://youtu.be/1OpAgZvYXLQ